# Need to pass the source ip from AWS gateway to NodeJS api application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway as an HTTP proxy to my rest api application. The thing is, I can't seem to find a way to get the client's IP address or to pass it through to my application(NodeJS API) from the API gateway. The only way I saw was to use a lambda function, but I can't use it because it has to be an HTTP integration.

How I can pass the source IP from AWS gateway to NodeJS API?

How we can access the source IP from NodeJS API?

Comment: Try using ```event['requestContext']['http']['sourceIp']```

Comment: This can be retrieved from the lambda function. But  we need the same nodejs API application

Comment: Can't you access the event in your nodejs application?

Comment: No. I have a NodeJS API application deployed in elastic beanstalk

Comment: How I can pass the values to node js API application from AWS API gateway